# Passing returned variables into a different method

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass the mark variable I returned into a different method so that it can be checked to determine the grade. When I try to run the program however it tells me that it can't find the symbol "mark" that I'm passing into the determineGrade method. I'm wondering how I'm supposed to pass mark into determineGrade so that the program can run?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeClassifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        title();
        getMark();
        determineGrade(mark);
        displayGrade(mark, grade);
    }

    public static void title() {
        System.out.println("Grade Classifier\n****************");
    }

    public static int getMark() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter exam mark :> ");
        int mark = in.nextInt();

        return mark;
    }

    public static String determineGrade(int mark) {
        String grade;

        if (100 >= mark >= 70)
            grade = "Grade A (Pass)";
        else if (69 >= mark >= 60)
            grade = "Grade B (Pass)";
        else if (59 >= mark >= 50)
            grade = "Grade C (Pass)";
        else if (49 >= mark >= 40)
            grade = "Grade D (Pass)";
        else if (39 >= mark >= 0)
            grade = "Grade F (Fail)";
        else
            grade = "You did not input a valid number.";

        return grade;
    }

    public static void displayGrade(int mark, String grade) {
        if (100 >= mark >= 0)
            System.out.print("Congratulations, you are awarded a " + grade + ".");
        else
            System.out.print(grade);
    }

}
```

Comment: In `main` , use `int mark = getMark();`  and  `String grade = determineGrade(mark);` , or both variables will be unknown in this scope .

Comment: or just say: determineGrade(getMark());

Comment: `if (100 >= mark >= 70)` this is not a Java statement

Comment: @Stefan oops you're right! I wasn't even thinking about that, thanks! Also thank you Berger and Stultuske, super quick responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `getMark();` with `int mark = getMark();`
This will create a new int type variable mark and holds the value returned by `getMark()` which is then passed to `determineGrade(mark);`.

Also, in method `getMark()` there is no need to create variable `int mark`, just return as follow :

```
return in.nextInt();
```

Comment: Thanks for that last tip!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your mark variable inside main or class scope. The problem here is you have declared mark inside getMark(). So it is not accessible outside this method.